# CSS style submit like href tag

Tags: html, css, input, href

I have a `button` class that I wrote in CSS. It essentially displays block, adds some styles, etc. Whenever I add the class to `a` tags, it works fine - the a tag spans the entire width of its container like `display:block` should do... However, when I add the `button` class to an `input` button, Chrome, Safari, and Firefox all add a `margin-right: 3px`...

I've used the DOM inspector in both Chrome and Safari and NO WHERE should it be adding a extra 3px padding.

I tried adding `margin: 0 !important;` and/or `margin-right: 0 !important` to my `button` class in my CSS, but the browser STILL renders a 3px right margin!

Is this a known issue, and is there a CSS-based solution (i.e. **not** jQuery/javascript)

**CODE FOLLOWS:**

```
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #369;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 11px 20px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Could you paste your CSS for us?

Comment: You can skip `cursor: hand;` - you're immediately overriding it with `cursor: pointer;`

Comment: @Surreal Dreams - umm... wrong... there's this other browser called IE...

Comment: @seth.vargo: Internet Explorer has supported `cursor: pointer` since version 6, released almost a decade ago.

Comment: You're telling me that assigning a CSS rule one value and then another gives you both?  I'm telling you that you're setting it to hand and then overwriting that with pointer.  Also, the only browser that doesn't support pointer is IE 5.5, see [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html).  If you need to support IE 5.5, I would suggest you have much worse problems than an extra line of CSS.  Also, note that if you *are* trying to support IE 5.5, those two lines are in the wrong order.  Assign pointer first, then hand.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this behaviour, though admittedly the only element I have any knowledge of is the `submit` button: [JS Fiddle repro-attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/jZD8w/). Am I missing something? (The jQuery's there to provide measurements of the margins of the element, not to influence anything.)

Comment: you're only looking at `input`. I'm comparing `<a href="#" class="button"...>` to `<input type="submit" class="button"...>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `<input>` element has a number of oddities.  Where possible, use the `<button>` element instead, that's a lot more reliable.

Comment: will that eliminate issues with the margins?

Comment: @seth.vargo, nope. Trying to style form elements is a pain in the butt.

Comment: grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

Answer (score 0):

if you add

```
width:100%;
```

to your existing code.It will fill the container and get rid of the random 3px right-margin.

Comment: right... and then the elements get pushed out of their container because they have padding

Comment: OK, I'm trying to mimic that, but with no luck. Any chance you could put up the container CSS so I can get a better understanding of what's going on with that.